# My wife can cast videos from her phone to our Chromecast, but I can't. What gives?

Tags: chromecast

She has a Samsung Galaxy Note 8, while I have a Google Pixel 3. I can cast if the app in question (e.g. YouTube or Hulu) supports casting with a built-in cast button, but if I used the system screen mirroring cast feature from the pull-down menu (say, for an app that doesn't support casting internally, such as Spectrum), I can't cast videos - the part of the screen where the video is appears black on the TV. This sounds like some sort of DRM issue, but why would it only affect my phone and not hers? Is there any way to cast videos from my phone?

Comment: Is your device rooted or at least its bootloader, unlocked?

Comment: It's not rooted, and I don't think I unlocked the bootloader (I don't even know what that means); do Pixels come with pre-unlocked bootloaders, perhaps? Does installing a custom launcher such as Nova count as unlocking the bootloader?

Comment: Videos are usually decoded in hardware and directly written to the frame buffer (special graphics memory). The screen cast is generated by different memory region and therefore does not include the video. This effect is common to all hardware accelerated video players, even on a PC/Windows this is the case.

Comment: Hmm, I wonder why my wife's phone would be able to cast videos, then? Does the Note 8 render videos in software, perhaps? Is there a flag i can set to make my phone do the same thing?

Comment: @ekolis May be the graphics driver on the Note 8 works different and provides a deeper access for the screen cast component that includes the decoded video?